# error in anova.lme

Tags: r, anova, lme4-nlme

I'm using R for multilevel modeling, and I'm a beginner. When I try to compare my random intercept model to a random intercept model with my predictor, I get the following error:

> Error in anova.lme(randomInterceptOnly, randomInterceptMedia1) :
>   all fitted objects must use the same number of observations

I know that one solution is to only use a subset of the data, only including the columns that are relevant to my current research question. I did that, and it did work. However, when I went back and tested the difference between a fixed and random intercept model using this subset of data, it showed no significant difference, therefore no need for multilevel modeling. If I use the same dataset, there is a significant difference, so I do need to use multilevel stats.

I'm wondering if anyone knows why this is happening? The data doesn't change between the two tries, it's just a subset of the same data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have a NA in one of the variables that, when that observation is removed, is causing the number of observations to be different between the models.

As an example, if you have 100 observations and variables Y, A, and B. There's an NA in B.  So the model Y ~ A has 100 valid observations, but the model Y ~ A + B has only 99 valid observations.